# Lubuntu 18.04 fresh install slow boot time on dell D630

Tags: boot, dell

I'm new to Lubuntu and Linux in general.

I've tried to revive an old Dell D630 laptop by installing Ubuntu 18.04 x64.

I have solved a few problems, but I'm still suffering with very slow boot times and slow resume from suspend. The device has an SSD so I don't think it should be taking several minutes to boot as it is doing currently.

```
$ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 35.819s (kernel) + 1min 4.839s (userspace) = 1min 40.659s
graphical.target reached after 1min 4.825s in userspace
```

---

```
$ systemd-analyze blame
         31.839s lightdm.service
         31.838s plymouth-quit-wait.service
         31.780s plymouth-start.service
         30.309s systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
          6.231s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          2.121s apparmor.service
          1.492s dev-sda5.device
           509ms upower.service
           467ms udisks2.service
           443ms keyboard-setup.service
           439ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
           381ms NetworkManager.service
           347ms networkd-dispatcher.service
           306ms systemd-journal-flush.service
           301ms swapfile.swap
           278ms systemd-journald.service
           238ms systemd-rfkill.service
           213ms accounts-daemon.service
           201ms grub-common.service
           196ms avahi-daemon.service
           194ms apport.service
           179ms ModemManager.service
           162ms wpa_supplicant.service
```

---

```
$ systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @1min 4.825s
└─multi-user.target @1min 4.825s
  └─getty.target @1min 4.825s
    └─getty@tty1.service @1min 4.824s
      └─system-getty.slice @1min 4.821s
        └─setvtrgb.service @1min 4.816s +3ms
          └─systemd-user-sessions.service @33.079s +7ms
            └─network.target @33.069s
              └─NetworkManager.service @32.717s +349ms
                └─dbus.service @32.679s
                  └─basic.target @32.591s
                    └─sockets.target @32.590s
                      └─avahi-daemon.socket @32.590s
                        └─sysinit.target @32.587s
                          └─cryptsetup.target @32.587s
                            └─systemd-ask-password-wall.path @303ms
                              └─-.mount @261ms
                                └─system.slice @265ms
                                  └─-.slice @261ms
```

What could be the issue here and how can I fix it?

Comment: This Lubuntu x64 is installed on SSD. The truth is that: 1): windows 7 is booting on the same drive in 20 seconds. 2) Lubuntu x86 on very old Toshiba L20 ssd is booting in 30 seconds with no black screens. So I think that something is going wrong - how to find out what is wrong?

Comment: I have to apologize, because the initial comment was intended for another question.  Anyway, the first four lines are probably the cause.  I am not entirely clear what is booting when and why, but that's probably irrelevant, as long as Windows and Ubuntu don't boot at the same time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Slow boot times since 18.04 installation on Dell D630](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029636/slow-boot-times-since-18-04-installation-on-dell-d630)

Answer (score 0):

As proposed in [Slow boot times since 18.04 installation on Dell D630](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029636/slow-boot-times-since-18-04-installation)

I changed the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line in `/etc/default/grub` to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="video=SVIDEO-1:d"
```

And ran `sudo update-grub`.

Now my boot time is about 30 sec:

```
$ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 5.053s (kernel) + 32.055s (userspace) = 37.108s
graphical.target reached after 32.038s in userspace
```